# CLR stored procedure with varbinary(max) OUTPUT fails, but same procedure works as T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlclr

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[brbackup]
    @dataID [nvarchar](max),
@backupdata [varbinary](max) OUTPUT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [SQLBackupRestore].[StoredProcedures].[BackupStuff]
GO
```

Which maps back to this CLR Stored procedure code:

```
public class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void BackupStuff(string dataID, out byte [] backupdata)
    {
       [..body omitted..]
    }
 }
```

This works just fine, I can call it in t-sql on the server just fine like this:

```
declare @backupdata varbinary(max);
exec brbackup "dataIDNumber", @backupdata output;
```

I get the expected output (several megabytes of data in @backupdata).  What I'd like to do is call this from C# through a client, but this doesn't work:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnString");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("brbackup", conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataID", "dataIDNumber");
        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@backupdata", 
                                           SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This query doesn't give an error, and it runs for a while (as expected), but `p.Value` has nothing in it but a `byte[0]`.  I've tried variations of setting the length to something other than -1, and setting `p.Value` to a `byte[]` large enough to hold the results, but no joy.

However, strangely enough creating a small t-sql stored procedure to wrap around the CLR stored procedure DOES work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AA_JUST_TESTING
@stuff varbinary(max) output
AS
BEGIN
declare @backupdata varbinary(max);
exec brbackup 'dataIDNumber', @backupdata output;
set @stuff = @backup;
END
GO
```

And then calling the wrapper AA_JUST_TESTING with this C# code:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnString");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AA_JUST_TESTING", conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@stuff",
                                          SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Works just peachy.  `p.Value` winds up with a `byte []` of just the right size filled with the correct data.

So... I don't see the difference other than one calls a CLR stored procedure and the other calls a T-SQL stored procedure, even though they're both using a `varbinary(max) output` to return the value.  I'm looking for:

- A plausible explanation, pointer to documentation, etc... that tells me why this works like it does.
- Some kind of work-around so I don't have to have the wrapper stored procedure, and can maybe just accomplish what I need calling the CLR SP directly from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. Try changing the C# code from :

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void BackupStuff(string dataID, out byte [] backup)
{
   [..body omitted..]
}
```

To :

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
...

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void BackupStuff(string dataID, out SqlBinary backup)
    {
       [..body omitted..]
       byte[] result = ... // get byte array to return
       backup = new SqlBinary(result);
    }
```

Using SqlBinary as the return type of the C# routine works for me.

**EDIT :** 
Well, using either SqlBinary or byte[] both work for me. 
Is your varbinary(max) parameter called "@backup" or "@backupdata" ? Looks like the sample code you show uses both. 
i.e. try changing :

```
  SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@backupdata", 
                                           SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
```

to :

```
  SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@backup", 
                                           SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
```

Comment: Sorry, inconsistency in the "scrubbing for public consumption" of the code.  They're both named something... proprietary.  :)   I'll fix the example above.